# Permission issues to modify files inside a container

Tags: docker, file, visual-studio-code, permissions, edit

I attach vs code to a docker container.

I `git clone` a github repo inside the container.

I open a file inside the repository and modify it.

I am unable to save the file. I keep getting the following error message:

[image]